# ASP.NET Page Request Stage...

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle, internals

During the Page Request stage (prior to the Page life cycle), how does ASP.NET determine whether or not the Page needs to be 1) parsed and compiled for the first time or 2) re-parsed and re-compiled due to a markup change (assuming "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" = true) or assembly change?  I can make some pretty safe assumptions, but does anyone know exactly how ASP.NET makes these determinations?

The ASP.NET Page Life Cycle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

**EDIT:**  So, "first time" is determined as the very first resource request off the ASP.NET web site; soooooo, it's not a question of what Page or resource (singular) needs to be parsed and compiled the "first time" *it* is requested, rather ASP.NET parses and compiles EVERYTHING the FIRST TIME ANY Page or resource is requested.  "Reparse and recompile" occurs in what appears to be a "lazy" fashion: when a change to a dynamically compiled file takes place, this invalidates the previously compiled, cached version of that file; this triggers recompilation of it and all effected resources THE NEXT TIME THE CODE IS REQUESTED - depending on the change made, 1-n to all files may have to be recompiled.

Thanks @Mass for the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

Comment: [Caching ASP.NET Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find all the answers you need at the link below:

Compiling on First Request

Recompiling on Change

Compilation Output

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: I guess I was really looking for the internals; in other words, is hash used to check the changed resources against the asp.net cache to determine change? is it timestamp, or other criteria, or a combination of these?  Anyhow, I will accept this answer. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second point ("re-parsed and re-compiled due to a markup change"):

There is a filesystem monitor started by the HTTP runtime. You may want to explore the `HttpRuntime.StartMonitoringDirectoryRenamesAndBinDirectory()` method using the Reflector.

Monitoring is affected by the `FCNMode` registry key setting under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET (x86)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET (x64)

Comment: Cool beans, TY much, these are the details I am looking for.